# FreeMarker Form for nested Object

Tags: java, freemarker

I am trying to write freemarker template but could not able to parse with my object class.

My POJO is

```
public class Metrix {

    @Id
    String _id;
    String loginId;
    Date date;
    List<MatrixDetail> headers;

    //All getters and setters
}

public class MatrixDetail {

    String header;
    int time;
    String detail;

//All getters and setters

}
```

//Controller after saving form

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/matrix/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public View saveMatrix(@ModelAttribute Metrix matrix, ModelMap model) {  
        System.out.println("Reachecd in matrix save" );
        return new RedirectView("/TrackerApplication/header.html");  
    }
```

FTL template form part

```
<form name="matrix" action="matrix/save.html" method="post">
    <table class="datatable" align:"center">

    <tr>
    <th>Login Id:</th>  <th> <input type="text" name="loginId" value= ${matrixList.loginId} required /> </th> 
    </tr>

    <tr> <td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Header</th>  <th>Time</th> <th>Details</th>
    </tr>


**//  I am not getting how this nested object which is of type List<MatrixDetail> 
//  will get parse in my form.**
  <#list matrixList.headers as header>
    <spring:bind path = "MatrixDetail">
    <tr>
           <td> <input name = "header" value =  ${header.header} /> </td>
           <td> <input name = "time" value = ${header.time} /> </td>
           <td> <input name = "detail" value =  ${header.detail} /></td></tr> 
   </#list>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
```

How can we write freemarker template for form processing of such kind of nested object?
I am getting issues in form submission.

Comment: If you don't tell what exactly is the problem, like an error message or other details, you will hardly get an answer.

Comment: The problem is on submitting a form matrix.headers are coming null.  I am only getting matrix.loginId and nothing else.

Comment: And have you checked the output of the template? You should quote the values, like value="${something}", if there can be space and such in them (also you should escape them, preferably with `#escape`, but that's OT now.)

Comment: what's MatrixDetail??

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against this.

Forms might be displayable in email in some cases, but [they may not always work in the email client](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/forms/), not to mention those that only ever read emails in text-only form won't be able to use them whatsoever.

If you need users to enter a form, link to a page on your site and have the form there instead.